# Whats is the proper definition of guard

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

While reading *Villette*, a 19th-century novel by Charlotte Brontë, I came across the word *guard* used in a different way than I had known hitherto:

> I was up the next morning an hour before daybreak, and finished my guard, kneeling on the dormitory floor...

From the above sentence I infer that the word carries a religious connotation—a morning prayer, a sermon or perhaps a rite.

Finding it odd, I consulted numerous online dictionaries, amongst which are [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/guard?showCookiePolicy=true) and [findwords](http://findwords.info/term/guard), but alas the search yielded no fitting result, so I resort to enlist your help.

The closest definition was 'posture of readiness or defence'; however, it doesn't coincide with the overall meaning of the sentence as I, perhaps wrongly, understand it.

The woman speaking is a Protestant, a detail that may or may not prove to be useful.

Comment: The closest definition is possibly [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/guard) n 15.
a. the act or duty of protecting, restraining, or supervising >> So. guard duty, or a spell of guard duty; perhaps used for a vigil.

Comment: It is the "bright little chainlet of silk and gold" which she is embroidering in the previous chapter, which in fact gives its name to the title of the previous chapter: "He asked at what I was working; and I said I was making a watchguard."

Comment: If you read on to the next paragraph, you will see that "guard" is used again: "I duly detached and re-attached it, then coiled compactly the completed guard". It seems to be some form of jewelry the narrator is crafting. It is in the form of a chain, made with silk and beads, and she completes it by attaching the clasp from her own necklace.

Comment: Oh, your are all right, she is indeed talking about the watchguard.Thanks a lot

Comment: @YoavKallus: Impressive. Why don't you post it as an answer. You'd gain rep and we'd this post wont show in the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 5):

If you read on to the next paragraph, you will see that "guard" is used again: "I duly detached and re-attached it, then coiled compactly the completed guard". It seems to be some form of jewelry the narrator is crafting. It is in the form of a chain, made with silk and beads, and she completes it by attaching the clasp from her own necklace.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Victorian guard chain with clasp]

An example of a Victorian ladies' **guard chain**, worn around the neck. These were long chains, with a clasp for attaching pocket watches, lockets, spectacles and muffs.

Comment: A simple answer to a simple question.  I must be on the wrong site.

Comment: Hi @Bob do you know how to tick the correct answer?